# terms related to veiling

Tags: word-usage

What is the best construction of a sentence to talk of a lady who's covered herself fully with a sheet or any other stuff like a gown?

1. She is wearing a veil.
2. She is observing a veil.

My question is about, the verb: does it have to be 'wear' or 'observe'?

Secondly, does the word 'veil' cover the meaning of the situation mentioned i.e. body fully covered? Is a veil body-length stuff?

Or what about: She's veiled herself.

Comment: I would use the last version as *veil* and *unveil* can both be used as verbs. Unless I'm mistaken *unveil* is only a verb :-) *Unveiling a mystery*.

Comment: I think it is quite possible that a veil for example only covers the face of a woman.